# did not came expected output in terminal in c

Tags: c, output

i'm trying to create simple programme in c using pipe() and fork() functions. programme works correctly but output has extra four characters when it prints. please help me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    int pip[2];
    pid_t pid;
    int ret;
    char msg[17];

    ret = pipe(pip);    

    if(ret == -1) {
        perror("pipe");
        exit(1);
    }

    pid = fork();

    if(pid>0) {
        write(pip[1] , "Hello from parent" , 17);
    }
    else {
        read(pip[0] , msg , 17);
        printf("%s\n", msg);
    }
}
```

terminal output is

> Hello from parent-/X�

when it runs change the last four characters. but i did not enter than characters. please help me.

Comment: It is good practice to zero-out any memory that you intend to use. The `msg[]` in your case, try `msg[17] = {0};`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are attempting to save 17-characters long string, then your variable to save it must have 18 character for trailing zero char which indicates end of string.

```
char msg[17];
```

must be

```
char msg[18];
```

Later, while you read, function does not deal with strings, meaning you need to *close* your string manually:

```
read(pip[0] , msg , 17);
msg[17] = 0; //Close your string here
printf("%s\n", msg);
```

You might want to learn more about [strings in C](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_strings.htm).